# Other browser windows don't go back to user login page after Meteor.logout()

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have written a meteor application with user login. After a user logs out, the application redirects to the user login page. However, when they are multiple tabs in the browser (or multiple browser windows) where the application is active (and the user is logged in), only the active tab or browser window goes back to the user login page. In the other window it seems the user is still logged in. However, when the user does some further work in the other window, nothing is synced with the db on the server anymore. I thought Meteor.logout() is reactive, so how is it possible that the other browser tabs or windows don't refresh?

I have the folowwing in my router?js file:

```
var filters = {
 isLoggedIn : function(pause) {
  if(!Meteor.user()){
   this.render('login');
  } else {
   this.next();
  }
 }

....

}

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.isLoggedIn);
```

After pushing the logout button the following js code is executed

```
Meteor.logout();
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you make clicking "logout" change something that you know is reactive and put that reactive element somewhere where it will always be rendered (say in the header of the page or before your `{{> yield}}`)?

Comment: First I had created my own UI to sign in. To test what you ask for I've changed my code: now I use the accounts-ui package from the Meteor accounts system in combination with the {{> loginButtons}} template. When I push 'sign out' it should be reactive. When I try this in the 'microscope' app (from the Meteor book) it is. When I try this in my app, unfortunately it is not. Also when I run the command Meteor.logout in the console, the active browser windows logs out, but in the other browser windows, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Meteor.logoutOtherClients
```

[Meteor.logoutOtherClients](https://www.meteor.com/accounts) should log out all sessions. It is designed for situations where the user is logged in on multiple devices and wants to log out on all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I didn't want to use a global redirect on logout, but on some templates to redirect to another template if logout happens.

Following Autumn Leonard's comment, I made this work by having the particular template reactive by creating a template.mytemplate.onCreated function and inside there put an autorun function checking Meteor.user() and doing the redirect.

I hope this approach helps others :)